# The text is hidden from content

Tags: html, css, alignment, positioning

I have a problem on my website where a piece of text falls underneath another `div`.

The problem is in the sidebar, as you can see in the following image. The text on the left side falls under the content, which is on the ride side of it.

[image]

Here is a JSFiddle example of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/j87Gy/

I think that the problem is in the following `CSS` code, but i'm not sure:

```
.wrapper{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.sidebar{
    width:25%;
    background:#262625;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: the sidebar seems to be larger than what it should be, and its content is hidden from the content.

Comment: It seems right on firefox/ubuntu. which browsers do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/bukfixart/j87Gy/2/)

Just remove the line `width:100%;` in the css from the selector `.footer`.
The class has a padding (5%). If you are using a width, the padding will be added to it, so the sum will be

```
100% + 5% (left) + 5% (right) = 110%.
```

This will be oversized everytime.

Comment: thanks, i didn't noticed that. thank you very much for the help.